# How to get the userId of a newly registered user in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

Im trying to get the `userId` stored in the `AspNetUsers` table and store it in my `Student` table during the registration process.

How do I get the `userId` of the newly created user (**not the logged in user**) from the `AspnetUsers` table and store it in a seperate table **DURING** the registration process?

My controller:

```
public ActionResult Create(ExpandedUserDTO paramExpandedUserDTO)
{
    try
    {
        if (paramExpandedUserDTO == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        var Email = paramExpandedUserDTO.Email.Trim();
        var UserName = paramExpandedUserDTO.Email.Trim();
        var Password = paramExpandedUserDTO.Password.Trim();

        UserName = Email.ToLower();

        // Create user

        var objNewAdminUser = new ApplicationUser { UserName = UserName, Email = Email};

        var AdminUserCreateResult = UserManager.Create(objNewAdminUser, Password);

        if (AdminUserCreateResult.Succeeded == true)
        {
            string strNewRole = Convert.ToString(Request.Form["Roles"]);

            if (strNewRole != "0")
            {
                // Put user in role
                UserManager.AddToRole(objNewAdminUser.Id, strNewRole);

                //Put user in student table
                if (strNewRole == "Student")
                {


                }
            }

            return Redirect("~/Admin");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ViewBag.Roles = GetAllRolesAsSelectList();
        return View("Create");
    }
}
```

Comment: `objNewAdminUser.Id` is the Id of the new user.

Comment: `objNewAdminUser.Id` is the userId. what else do you want?

Comment: Hmm, given the new user ID is used to add a role a couple of lines above. I find it odd that you had to ask this question!

Answer (score 0):

If you create the user an Id is created automatically for you.

```
 var objNewAdminUser = new ApplicationUser { UserName = UserName, Email = Email};
 var userId = objNewAdminUser.Id //18479b0a-17cd-4a76-9e9e-d90a8480617b
```

Answer (score 0):

```
you can try this

if(AdminUserCreateResult.Succeeded == true)
{
//Get Details of currently registered User
    var RegisteredUser= SignInManager.UserManager.FindByEmail(Email);
//Extract userid from user Details.
    var userid=RegisteredUser.Id;
//this will give you the ID stored in aspnetusers of currentUser
}
```